# \label and numbering is not working

Tags: numbering, labels

I am facing with one problem.

I want to apply numbering and \label function.

But, it does not working with align*, aligned.

```
 \begin{align*}\label{eq:rewrittenNE} 
 \left\{\begin{aligned}
 \begin{split}
 \dot{\zeta}   &= \nu  \\ 
 \dot{\nu}     &= -ge_{3}+R_{e_{3}}(\frac{b}{m}\sum \Omega _{i}^2) \\ 
 \dot{R}       &= R\hat{\omega} \\ 
 I\dot{\omega} &= -\omega \times {I}\omega - \sum J_{r}(\omega \times e_{3})\Omega_{i}+\tau_{a} 
 \end{split}
 \end{aligned}\right.
 \end{align*}\newline
```

Answer (score 4):

`align*` is not numbered so you can not use `\label` as there is no number to reference, but also  there is no alignment there at all so perhaps you intended `\begin{equation}` to get a number?

There should never be a  `\newline` after a display.

I also removed `split`.

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:rewrittenNE} 
 \left\{\begin{aligned}
 \dot{\zeta}   &= \nu  \\ 
 \dot{\nu}     &= -ge_{3}+R_{e_{3}}(\frac{b}{m}\sum \Omega _{i}^2) \\ 
 \dot{R}       &= R\hat{\omega} \\ 
 I\dot{\omega} &= -\omega \times {I}\omega - \sum J_{r}(\omega \times e_{3})\Omega_{i}+\tau_{a} 
 \end{aligned}\right.
 \end{equation}
```